# Disallow words that start with '.'

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a pattern that will fail under these conditions:

When a period is entered:

- at first position
- beginning of any word (e.g “.test name” or “test .name”
- at last position

When slash is entered:

- at first position,
- beginning of any word,
- followed with a space or at last position

I was trying something like that: `(^\.|\s\.|\.$|^\/|\/\s|\/$)`
I tried to negate it but no success...

Initially we had a regexp: `^[A-Za-z0-9ùûüÿàâæçéèêëïîôÙÛÜŸÀÂÇÉÈÊËÏÎÔ\. \-'\/]*$`
I was trying to merge my attempt with the initial regexp we had... but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can there be multiple adjacent dots or slashes? https://regex101.com/r/fHIR9J/1 or else perhaps https://regex101.com/r/fHIR9J/2

Comment: Most programming languages already have a library function that is better at this particular operation than a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use your character class and omit the forward slash and the dot. Use that to match the first character followed by matching a `.` or `/` and 1+ times the character class to match words with at least 2 characters.

To match multiple words divided be a space you could repeat the first pattern.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9ùûüÿàâæçéèêëïîôÙÛÜŸÀÂÇÉÈÊËÏÎÔ'-](?:[./]?[A-Za-z0-9ùûüÿàâæçéèêëïîôÙÛÜŸÀÂÇÉÈÊËÏÎÔ'-]+)+(?: [A-Za-z0-9ùûüÿàâæçéèêëïîôÙÛÜŸÀÂÇÉÈÊËÏÎÔ'-](?:[./]?[A-Za-z0-9ùûüÿàâæçéèêëïîôÙÛÜŸÀÂÇÉÈÊËÏÎÔ'-]+)+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fHIR9J/1)

If consecutive dots and forward slashes are are allowed you could change `[./]?` to `[./]*`

Another option is to use negative lookaheads to assert no space before and after or matching `/` or `.` at the start or at the end of the string.

```
^(?!.*(?:^| )[./])(?!.*[./](?: |$))(?!.*([/.])\1)[A-Za-z0-9ùûüÿàâæçéèêëïîôÙÛÜŸÀÂÇÉÈÊËÏÎÔ './-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWW1iz/1)

If consecutive dots and forward slashes are are allowed you could omit this lookahead `(?!.*([/.])\1)`

Comment: Thanks!!!! The only case where it's not working is for example: "St. Patrick" should be allowed. I think I can figure this one out. Thank you for help!!!!